# 'Children' Property in Dash Python html

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm pretty confused by what 'children' even does in Dash html. Why does it even exist? Why would you use it? I tried reading the documentation, but it hasn't been very helpful.

With reference to the block of code below:

- What does the children property even do in the first line?
- Couldn't you replace children with something like 'figure' for the plots?

Block of Code:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # TODO1: Add title to the dashboard
    html.H1("Airline Dashboard by CK", style = {'text-align':'center'}),
    # REVIEW2: Dropdown creation
    # Create an outer division
    html.Div([
        # Add an division
        html.Div([
            # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for report type
            html.Div(
                [
                    html.H2('Report Type:', style={'margin-right': '2em'}),
                ]
            ),
            # TODO2: Add a dropdown
                dcc.Dropdown(id = 'input-type',
                    options = [{'label':'Yearly Airline Performance Report', 'value': 'OPT1'},
                    {'label':'Yearly Average Flight Delay Statistics', 'value': 'OPT2'}],
                    multi = False,
                    placeholder = 'Select a Report Type',
                    style={'width': '80%', 'padding': '3px', 'font-size': '20px', 'text-align-last': 'center'}
            )
            # Place them next to each other using the division style
        ], style={'display': 'flex'}),

        # Add next division
        html.Div([
            # Create an division for adding dropdown helper text for choosing year
            html.Div(
                [
                    html.H2('Choose Year:', style={'margin-right': '2em'})
                ]
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='input-year',
                         # Update dropdown values using list comphrehension
                         options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in year_list],
                         placeholder="Select a year",
                         style={'width': '80%', 'padding': '3px', 'font-size': '20px', 'text-align-last': 'center'}),
            # Place them next to each other using the division style
        ], style={'display': 'flex'}),
    ]),

    # Add Computed graphs
    # REVIEW3: Observe how we add an empty division and providing an id that will be updated during callback
    html.Div([], id='plot1'),

    html.Div([
        html.Div([], id='plot2'),
        html.Div([], id='plot3')
    ], style={'display': 'flex'}),

    # TODO3: Add a division with two empty divisions inside. See above disvision for example.
    html.Div([
        html.Div([], id='plot4'),
        html.Div([], id='plot5')
    ], style = {'display':'flex'})
])


# Callback function definition
# TODO4: Add 5 ouput components
@app.callback(
              [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
               Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')],
              # REVIEW4: Holding output state till user enters all the form information. In this case, it will be chart type and year
              [Output("plot1", 'children'), Output("plot2", "children"),
               Output("plot3", "children"), Output("plot4", "children"),
               Output("plot5", "children")
               ])
```

Comment: " I tried reading the documentation, but it hasn't been very helpful." Specifically what documentation did you look at? What text did you find in there that mentioned `children`, and what did you find confusing or uninformative about it? It looks like you're using a library that represents HTML in some way. Do you understand what HTML looks like? Do you understand what it means for one HTML tag to be a child of another?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is what I looked at: https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks    Basically it seems to say it's not really required for anything? If that's the case why have it there anyways? What exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes maybe this question could be edited to be more clear, but this is confusing. E.g., in the book 'Interactive Dashboards with Plotly and Dash' they discuss `children` in one page, drop it without explanation in another; it can be pretty unclear what is happening. In the docs it says `it's always the first attribute which means that you can omit it`. What?!  How does that follow? This is not a feature of Python generally. It could use some more explanation. Seems worthwhile question for SO even if this particular question could be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/layout) of the docs:

> 5. The children property is special. By convention, it's always the first attribute which means that you can omit it: html.H1(children='Hello Dash') is the same as html.H1('Hello Dash'). Also, it can contain a string, a number, a single component, or a list of components.

Some components, such as `html.Div` and `html.P`, accept a value for their `children` prop. Others, such as `dcc.Graph` or `dcc.Dropdown` do not, and require other props in order to function properly.

As @KarlKnechtel mentioned in his comment, when one component is a child of another, it represents a nesting of the first component inside the other. The following are analogous:

In Dash:

```py
html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('This is some text'),
        html.P('This is also some text'),
    ]
)
```

In HTML:

```html
<div>
  <h1>This is some text</h1>
  <p>This is also some text</p>
</div>
```

I hope that answers your questions.

Edit:

Adding `style` after `children` to this `html.Div` would allow you to change the styles of the `Div`, which may impact the styles of the components nested inside it, but that is not the purpose of the `children` prop. As the docs mention, you can either explicitly set `children=` whatever, or you can pass the same value in first, with no explicit key word argument, and Dash will treat that as the `children` prop. Either way, behind the scenes, the component is still receiving a value for its `children` property.

The purpose of the `children` property is to allow users to nest components, just as we do in raw HTML. Without the `children` prop, it would not be possible to do things like group related items together by containing them in the same parent element (ex. putting navigation items inside a top navigation bar).

Comment: Interesting, so if you added a style after children in your code, would it style everything inside the div? Is that the purpose of children = [] here?

Comment: I added an edit with more explanation in response to this question.

Comment: @coralvanda What about `component_property='children'` in `app.callback`. Why are we using `children` there?

Comment: @Lostman That makes the callback reference that prop for the specified (by ID) component, either as an `Input`, `State`, or `Output` depending on how the callback is set up.